# Applying Formula on a SQL Column

Tags: sql, formula, numeric

Suppose I have a numerical column and I want to apply a non trivial (not sum or avg) formula to the values. How would I write the query to get the desired values.

As an example, suppose Table T has column called number and I want to find product of the reciprocal of the number.

```
T.number
--------
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to get the value:

> 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5

**How do I achieve this?** I am familiar with grouping and aggregating, but here I do not need to group, but apply formula directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula is the sum of the reciprocal.  You would do:

```
select sum(1.0 / t.number)
from t;
```

Unfortunately, most databases do not support a `product` function.  You can do this by taking the log and adding them and then reversing the log.  The specific functions vary by database, but something like this:

```
select exp(sum(log(1.0 / t.number)))
from t;
```

Comment: what if I wanted to multiply, or  take square root after multiplying?

Comment: Depends on the database; most support `sqrt()`; if not that, then `pow()` or `power()`.

Comment: I guess the key is to find suitable substitution, just like you have demonstrated for product.

Answer (score 0):

This is more elaborately represented...

```
DECLARE @TempTbl TABLE
(
    Num DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO @TempTbl(Num) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @TempTbl(Num) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @TempTbl(Num) VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO @TempTbl(Num) VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO @TempTbl(Num) VALUES(5)


SELECT SUM(1.0/Num) FROM @TempTbl
```